Run Databricks (call pyspark functions) outside of Databricks then feed output as input to dashboard?
I have a bunch of notebooks in Databricks that are connected to company data tables. I run a series of functions on them to get back data insights. I want to know if there is a way to externally run databrick notebooks/functions outside of databricks and then feed that output as input to a dashboard. Ideally I'd like to be able to either directly run databricks notebooks externally and save the data as tables then load those tables into a dashboard. Two reason for this, 1. company data can only be reached through spark.table in databricks, and 2. leveraging the power of the Spark engine for big data processing.
I explored using the VSCODE extension for databricks, I was able to login using the Azure CLI (I am not an admin and have limited permissions) and attach my cluster. But when I a ran a notebook it was incredibly slow and not sure how to save from there.
More information about that here:
https://www.databricks.com/blog/2023/02/14/announcing-a-native-visual-studio-code-experience-for-databricks.html
I am also unable to generate a dbr token for using APIs.
Is there any other ways I can get the output of PySpark functions and access those data tables and feed into my dashboard?
Thanks!
I tried using the VSCODE databricks extension but even a simple python("hello world") took 1 minute to run.
I looked into running flask api or using requests to trigger notebooks to run but required dbr token which I do not have admin access to and would be unlikely to get.

Hello, have you tried to run with the Databricks REST API, and does it work? You'll need to get an API key from your Databricks administrator. Then use the python request library to send POST requests to the Databricks API.
